# "Feel committed to [gerund/infinitive]"

Tags: grammaticality, infinitives, gerunds, sense-verbs

Does "feel committed to" require an infinitive or gerund complement?

For example, which of the following is grammatical?

> - I feel committed to following up on that.
> - I feel committed to follow up on that.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

"I feel committed to following up on that." Or likewise "I am committed to following up on that", etc.

But as a verb, rather than an adjective:

"I have committed to follow up on that." or "I committed to follow up on that", etc.

Answer (score 0):

"To" is used as a preposition in "committed to" and not an infinitive marker. Therefore, what follows must be an object, which is a noun, and a gerund by definition functions as a noun. The previous answer is incorrect.

Comment: Thanks! That makes sense, the same phrase can be said with a verb but I was actually wondering about what follows after "to" in this form.

Answer (score 0):

If 'committed' always takes 'to' as a preposition, then it is always followed by the gerund (when it is followed by a verb form); prepositions are never followed by infinitives.  (That's what makes 'to' tricky in English: it can be a preposition or part of an infinitive.)  If you can look forward to a thing--a wedding, a party, the weekend, etc.--then 'to' is a preposition, in which case 'I look forward to seeing you' is correct (and not 'I look forward to see you.)  Similarly, since you can commit to a project, a partner, etc., 'to' is a preposition here, too, so it should be 'I committed to being there by 10.'

It is understandable that people want to say 'I committed to be there,' since the verb essentially means 'promised'--and 'promise' takes the infinitive.

Further complicating the decision between 'to + gerund' and 'to + infinitive' is that a verb's meaning may change in two different cases.  You proceed [go] to the gate in an airport, but you proceed [go on] to do something.

I hope this helps. 
Tim K.

Answer (score -1):

Either is correct.  Committed, while always taking the preposition "to" may be followed by either an infinitive form or the gerund (-ing) form.

http://www.englishgrammar.org/verbs-gerunds-infinitives/

Comment: The article deals with 'be committed to' _**not**_ 'commit to'.