# Is there a context where 'to neglect' and 'neglecting' are not compatible?

Tags: word-usage

I believe that to infinitive as a subject can be replaced by a gerund form, which is why

> To get up early is good.

always has the same meaning as

> Getting up early is good.

But a colleague of mine tells me this isn't always the case. I did not have a chance to have him elaborate on that. He cited the following sentence:

> Neglecting others means ignoring

and only said that because of '*ignoring*', you cannot use '*to neglect*' instead of '*neglecting*'.

Is he right? If so, why?

Comment: Why do you keep using the tilde?

Comment: If *"You are neglecting me"* is changed to *"You are to neglect me"*, it doesn't mean the same thing. And if *"I don't mean to neglect you"* is changed to *"I don't mean neglecting you"* it's no longer valid English at all.

Comment: @FumbleFingers: OP meant when the infinitive is the subject.

Comment: @Kaiser Octavius: I know, and I've already closevoted as a dup of one of the vast number of earlier questions regarding [infinitive/gerund](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/97431/) (not that one, as it happens). But although we both know that's what OP *means*, that's not what he's *asked*.

Comment: You do realise that your original question is many times broader than the refinement you go on to describe?

Answer (score 2):

The point your colleague is making is that you shouldn't mix forms. This is perhaps best explained using examples:

Correct:

> Neglecting means ignoring.
>
> To neglect means to ignore.

Incorrect:

> Neglecting means to ignore.
>
> To neglect means ignoring.

Comment: But is it ungrammatical to mix forms?

Comment: Mixing forms is to be avoided.

Comment: Isn't that a statement about style?

Comment: It was intended to be funny. However, I'd stick with terdon's recommendations myself, at least in those cases.

Answer (score 1):

> Neglecting others means ignoring [them].

I think you mean an object there, or the sentence would sound odd to my ear. In most cases where the gerund or infinite is the subject of object of a verb, you can replace one with the other (I can't think of an exception).

However, a gerund can be the object of a preposition, while an infinite normally cannot:

> After conquering Athens, Augustus paused.
>
> After *to conquer Athens...

There are also many verbs that only take one or the other. Lastly, there are cases where the two have different meanings:

> Cleopatra stopped looking at Marc Athony. = "She had been looking at him but now began doing something else."
>
> Cleopatra stopped to look at Marc Athony. = "She stopped doing whatever she was doing in order to look at him."

Comment: In _stop to look_, _to_ is not the infinitive-marker - it is the _to_ that is the equivalent of the French 'pour', 'in order to'. Compare _I have come to see your father_ and contrast _I have come to see the complexities involved in these structures_.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: Yes, you could say that (although they have the same origin, and they cannot always be distinguished).

Comment: _I came in order to see your father_ is not an example of catenation. _I tried to see your father_ is.   "It is most important to distinguish between a real catenative verb, such as decide I decided to work. and a normal verb followed by an infinitive of purpose (French: pour)" ( http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Appendix:English_catenative_verbs )

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: So what are you arguing here? What do you want me to do or say?

Comment: Your statements 'There are also many verbs that only take one or the other. Lastly, there are cases where the two have different meanings:' grossly over-simplify the different catenative (see at http://www.wordwizard.com/phpbb3/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=23577&hilit=phase+stood , for example) and non-catenative (as at the link above) verb + en-form and verb + ing-form structures.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth: "Grossly", really? Why? The question didn't seem to ask for linguistic theories. Nor did it ask about the differences between kinds of *to + inf.* or kinds of gerunds. Wasn't the way I explained it appropriate for the way the question was phrased? Is anything I said factually incorrect or inconsistent? If so, you are welcome to edit my answer.