# Commit to + inf vs + -ing

Tags: tenses

I thought "commit to" should be followed by "-ing", but the following ***[article](https://www.theguardian.com/us-news/2020/dec/08/trump-vaccine-summit-pfizer-deal)*** uses infinitive form of verb, as in the following sentence:

> "Under its contract with Pfizer, the Trump administration committed to buy an initial 100 million doses, with an option to purchase as many as five times more."

Does this occasion have a reason for such use, or it's simply a typo?

Comment: It's a legal usage.

Comment: A related question asked before ([feel committed to _gerund_ v _infinitive_](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/97431/feel-committed-to-gerund-infinitive#:~:text=It%20is%20understandable%20that%20people,'promise'%20takes%20the%20infinitive.&text=Committed%2C%20while%20always%20taking%20the,the%20gerund%20(%2Ding)%20form.)) but no satisfactory answer.

Comment: *Under its contract with Pfizer, the Trump administration committed **itself** to buy an initial 100 million doses* There is an omitted reflexive. *to buy an initial 100 million doses* is an infinitive NP, *to buying an initial 100 million doses* is a gerundive phrase, equivalent to a noun phrase. The infinitive implies the whole action as a unit - the gerund implies the process of the action from immediately after the start of the action to immediately before the end of the action.

Comment: @JohnLawler Yup, lots of legal usage [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22commit%20to%20buy%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en) and [here](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22commits%20to%20buy%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en), and that's without even dragging out the OED, which has this citation: *The second resolution..commits us to pay a share..of the sum of £15,000 asked for by the Imperial Government.*

Comment: @JohnLawler Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Traditionally one commits to a person or thing. That is, one commits to a **noun**.

> commit verb (PROMISE)   C2 [ I or T ] to promise or give your loyalty,
> time, or money **to a particular principle, person, or plan of action:**
>
> Like so many men, he has problems committing himself to a relationship.
> The government must commit itself to improving healthcare. Once we have committed to this course of action there is no going back.
>
> https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/commit

A gerund acts as a noun equivalent, so we can say, "He commits to VERBing"

In its traditional form, we don't commit infinitive.

**Answer**

I see "commit to buy" as an error. However English is always evolving so it may become standard in the future.

---

**EDIT**

See the comments below. The phrase appears to be standard in the world of commerce.

Comment: You sure about that? Consider [commits to buy](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22commits%20to%20buy%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en]) and [commit to buy](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22commit%20to%20buy%22&tbm=bks&lr=lang_en) samples.

Comment: @tchrist - Aah - Then it's a technical usage in the field of commerce.

Comment: The OED has this citation: *The second resolution..commits us to pay a share..of the sum of £15,000 asked for by the Imperial Government.* So more legalese.

Comment: @tchrist - I now see that John Lawler made a comment to that effect. I took him to mean legal in the sense of grammatically allowable!  I now see he was being literal.

Comment: @John Lawler - See my previous comment. Apologies!

Comment: No, he meant it's from the domain of law.